# Syntax error on token ";", . expected in JSP

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui

Syntax error on token ";", . expected
at `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>;`

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="resources/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />

<script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>


</head>


<body>
    <%
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>;
        data.add("a");
        data.add("b");
        data.add("c");
    %>
    <kendo:datePicker name="datePicker"></kendo:datePicker>
    <kendo:calendar name="calendar"></kendo:calendar>

    <kendo:dropDownList name="dropdownlist">
        <kendo:dataSource data="<%=data%>"></kendo:dataSource>
    </kendo:dropDownList>
</body>
</html>
```

when I try this code. There is a error "Syntax error on token ";", . expected" in Eclipse .

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `new`, you are calling for a constructor. The constructor is not just the class' name, as you are doing. It is like a method and thus require parameters.

The default constructor of `ArrayList` requires no parameters and thus can be called empty (`()`).

Your code should be:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
//                                            ^^--- added () here
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course this error message is a bit misleading as what you're really missing are the parenthesis for constructor's argument list.

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error itself only saying "Hey you had missed something" and that if you want to add some list to `ArrayList` you should use parenthesis in order to pass argument lists to constructor.

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here the empty parenthesis are indicating that we are passing an empty arguments-list.